# Is there a difference for conductivity along (111) plane and other directions for single crystal metals? Reflectivity shares the same principle?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, reflection, crystals

Single crystal can be Al, Ag and Au. Reflectivity is more for visible or not with wavelength having heavy absorption.

Comment: Do you mean to restrict the question to fcc metals only?

Answer (score 3):

If a crystal has cubic symmetry (which your examples Au, Ag and Al all have, due to having having an fcc-lattice), then the conduction tensor will be isotropic.

To see this, choose a coordinate system, where the axes point along three perpendicular symmetry axes of the crystal. Those exist in a cubic crystal, and when rotating one into the other the crystal will look the same.

Therefore, in this coordinate system, the conductivity tensor must have the form
$$ \underline{\sigma} = \sigma \underline 1 \tag{$*$}$$
(That is, it is a multiple of the unit matrix.) Since this tensor is invariant under rotations, equation $(*)$ holds in all coordinate systems.

Reflectivity, happens on the surface (and the crystal symmetry is broken by that surface), so the above argument does not hold. I am not sure about the specifics, but I could imagine slightly different reflection coefficients on different crystallographic axes. (E.g. due to differences of the interaction of the light with core atoms, and differences in the local conductivity near the surface due to the different packing of the surfaces along different crystallographic planes).